# UV map a sphere into wedges

Tags: uv

Is there a way to UV map a sphere into 4 wedges? I was provided a UV map from a 3D designer that had the art in 4 wedges, but I haven't found a tutorial on how to do so. Help?

Comment: You can mark edge creases to form the wedges, have you tried that?

Comment: What kind of sphere ICO / UV ...? Reference image of your case would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the edges that should be seams
2. Press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Mark Seam*
3. Select all with <kbd>A</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Unwrap*